# Mass transit does not track my command after publish

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, rabbitmq, outbox-pattern

my goal is to use mass transit transactional outbox pattern with rabbitmq and here is the configuration:

```
 private static void AddOutboxPattern(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMassTransit(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.AddEntityFrameworkOutbox<PersonalGoodsDbContext>(o =>
                {
                    o.QueryDelay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
                    o.UseSqlServer();
                    o.UseBusOutbox();
                });

                configuration.UsingRabbitMq((ctx, cfg) =>
                {
                    cfg.Host("rabbitmq");
                    //cfg.AutoStart = true;
                });
            });
        }
```

and my dbcontext:

```
       protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(typeof(CenterMapping).Assembly);

            modelBuilder.AddInboxStateEntity();

            modelBuilder.AddOutboxMessageEntity();

            modelBuilder.AddOutboxStateEntity();
        }
```

and my command handler that publish the command to the certain endpoint:

```
        public async Task Handle(CreateCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
                var personnelDoc = new NonPersonnelDocument(
                request.ImportationReason);
            
                documentsRepository.Create(personnelDoc);
                _eventBus.Publish(request);
        }
```

and here is my `Create and publisher` method that use mass transit:

```
        public new void Create(Document document)
        {
            dbContext.Set<Document >().Add(document);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void Publish<T>(T command) where T : IEvent
        {
            _publishendpoint.Publish(command);
        }
```

now there is a question:

- Why there is no date seed in my 3 tables created by mass transit even if my rabbit is down?

Note: I am using docker and every thing is up and running.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out the problem was my migration but I still confused about it

instead of using this code:

```
       await writeContext.Database.EnsureDeletedAsync();
       await writeContext.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync();
```

I changed it to this code:

```
        await writeContext.Database.MigrateAsync();
```

and now it work perfectly fine.